# Read a website using PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, webrequest

I want to call a website using PL/SQL and get the return value of it.

The main sense of the process is the call itself, I don't really need the given return value of the website.

How is it possible to execute a webcall as simple as possible in PL/SQL?

Thanks for help!

Flo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple:

```
response = utl_http.request(url);
```

where `response` is `VARCHAR2(2000)` as this call returns only the first 2000 bytes of the response.

Of course, you can retrieve the whole response document too, in 2000 bytes chunks. You can additionally set timeout, response error check, etc.

Available in Oracle 10*g*+. See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_http.htm).

Comment: just need to add : before = so -   response := utl_http.request(url);